# How to inject Spring configuration into TestExecutionListener of JUnit5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I'm running tests with JUnit5 + Spring Boot.

I've implemented a custom TestExecutionListener.

I'm trying to autowire the Environment object of Spring to this custom listener.

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class MyListener implements TestExecutionListener {

  @Autowired
  Environment env;

  @Override
  public void testPlanExecutionStarted(TestPlan testPlan) {
    System.out.println("Hi!");
  }
}
```

This is not working and I'm getting null for `env`.

As I understand, it is because JUnit is the one responsible to load this listener and not Spring.

Also the Spring context is loaded after that class is loaded and it is too late to inject.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thank you

Comment: You don't as JUnit5 doesn't know anything about Spring nor are those listeners executed or managed by Spring. You can use a Spring `TestExecutionLIstener` to do additional work.

Comment: The problem for me with Spring's 'AbstractTestExecutionListener' is that it doesn't support events at the beginning/end of the whole suite like JUnit's 'TestExecutionListener'

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by passing the `SpringExtension` class inside the junit `@ExtendWith` annotation.

Reference:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
class TestApplicationProperty {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull(environment);
        assertNotNull(environment.getProperty("spring.platform"));
        assertEquals("testplatform", environment.getProperty("spring.platform"));
    }
}
```

In my `application.properties` , i have these property

```
spring.platform: testplatform
```

**Note:** `classpath:application.properties` refers to `src/test/resources/application.properties`

Comment: I want to inject it to an implementation of TestExecutionListener of Junit, not to a test class.